# Idéias de como guardar acesso usuario

Tags: php, google, cookies, oauth

Estou usando o API do google em meu site. Quando o usuario concede autorização para usar a conta dele, o google me retorna dois tokens: um token q uso como "senha" para postar em nome do usuario e que expira em 1 hora e um segundo token fixo q uso pra atualizar o primeiro.

Guardo os dois no banco de dados. Minha duvida é: O que devo fazer? Salvar o primeiro token em cookies para sempre que o usuario acessar o site eu pegue ele e faça uma consulta para ver se expirou? Pois se salvar somente no banco como vou saber q o usuario logou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro Token você deve usar somente na sessão. O segundo pode ser armazenado no cookie, como você disse. Se a sessão do primeiro não existir (ou expirar_, voce deverá cria-lo, usando o token salvo no cookie

Comment: É uma ideia valida....assim não preciso fazer consultas em BD.

Comment: Legal que gostou Thiago. Inclusive procurei ontem na documentação mas não encontrei, mas me lembro que era uma pratica recomendada pelo Google, e as libs PHP faziam exatamente isso. Se ajudou e foi satisfatória, não esquece de marcar como resolvido. Valeu